# upload video to DailyMotion using GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, dailymotion-api

I'm trying to upload a video using Laravel and GuzzleHttp to DailyMotion. Here's my code:

```
$file = "3.mp4";
$fields["file"] = fopen($file, 'rb');
$res = $client->post($upload_url, [
   'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'],
    $fields
]);

$data3 =  $res->getBody();
$response_upload_video = json_decode($data3,true);
echo "<br>Getting dm upload video response: ";
print_r($response_upload_video);
```

`$upload_url` is a dynamically generated URL passed by DailyMotion. Upon executing the code above, I'll always get this error:

> Production.ERROR: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException:  
>   Client error:
>   POST
>   http://upload-02.sg1.dailymotion.com/upload?uuid=werewkrewrewrwer&seal=pppppppppppppppp`resulted
>   in a 400 Bad Request response: 
>       {"error":"invalid content range","seal":"yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"}
>        in /home/vagrant/Code/svc-titus/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:111

But I can upload video to the same upload URL using Postman, as displayed below:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think you need to specify content-type header guzzle will decide it automatically when you provide it a resource also the path of your video here seems problematic if video is stored at public directory you need to use public_path or respective path helper function to get its physical path
below should work in guzzleHttp 6 check sending form files here
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#uploading-data

```
$file = "3.mp4";
$res = $client->post($upload_url, [
     'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'file',
            'contents' => fopen(base_path($file), 'r') // give absolute path using path helper function 
        ]
    ]
]);

$data3 =  $res->getBody();
$response_upload_video = json_decode($data3,true);
echo "<br>Getting dm upload video response: ";
print_r($response_upload_video);
```

Comment: I got this error when tried to run your code "production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 2 passed to GuzzleHttp\Psr7\MultipartStream::addElement() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/svc-titus/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/MultipartStream.php on line 70".. Basically the line that throws the error is 'contents' => fopen(base_path($file), 'r')